# Use same reference after a child has been restarted by supervisor?

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I have a supervisor that can start dynamic children which are database servers. When a database server is abnormally killed, the supervisor restarts it, as it should.

But I have a reference, in the shell, to the database servers which looks like this:

```
Ref = {Pid, Ref}
```

E.g. {<0.52.0>,#Ref<0.0.0.146>}

When I want to do something with one of my database servers, it can look like this

```
database_server:write(Country,Capital,Ref).
```

E.g.

```
database_server:write(England,London,Ref).
```

So after a restart of that child, I want to be able to use the same Ref, even though the Pid has most likely changed when it was restarted.

Can't find any good solutions to this on the net :/

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code for database_server?

Comment: When a process dies its pid now references no process. The pid is never reused.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use the pid as your key.